# type 'Null' is not a subtype of type '_Location' of 'value'

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, android-widget

When I use Flutter track widget rebuilds it pop this error to me. [image]

**Here what error went to.**
[image]

Comment: Though, If i don't use track widget builds everything work find for me.

Comment: Can you attach snnipet and what you are passing to it

Comment: Note: Everything is static in container. beside log out Button i use.

Comment: Issue could be inside `Column`'s widget.

Comment: attach your `Column` too